# Populating dynamic select dropdown in json or xml (AND HOW)

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json, parsing

I need to populate this type of drop-down dynamically.

First is visible by default and on select of a particular option the corresponding 2nd drop-down will show up with its relevant options and hiding others.

Then on select of its option the third level drop-down should open up with the corresponding options.

Is it better to handle this data in XML or JSON? I am having a tough time in parsing this data using jQuery and AJAX. Can somebody help me in getting this up in dynamic way. My HTML doesn't have any tags. It should all be populated dynamically.

Thanks.

Here is how the HTML should be rendered. Again by default Only the first drop-down will be visible on select of its option the  second drop-down should be populated with its relevant options and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/wNjLm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use JSON. Here is a small example:

```
var data = [
    {
        name: "English Languages",
        values: ["English 1", "English 2", "English 3", "English 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "French Languages",
        values: ["French 1", "French 2", "French 3", "French 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "Spanish Languages",
        values: ["Spanish 1", "Spanish 2", "Spanish 3", "Spanish 4"]
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var category = data[i];
    var optgroup = $("<optgroup>").prop("label", category.name);
    for(var j = 0; j < category.values.length; j++)
        optgroup.append($("<option>").text(category.values[i]));

    $("#lang").append(optgroup);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wNjLm/2/

This will populate a select with the JSON data (already loaded in this case).

Comment: Are you not taking the country names in json object, where will they go.

Comment: The country names could also be in JSON. A simple array would do.

Comment: Is it possible to post a fiddle